# Find the closest class of object - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, select, closest

**Jquery**

```
  var courseSelect =  $(".courseSelected");
    $(".courseSelected").click(function()
    {
        if($(this).attr('checked'))
        {
            var selects = $(this).parent().next(".select").attr('title');
            alert(selects);
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
         <div>
            <div style="float:left;">
                <input name="course[]" type="checkbox" value="AUTOCAD" class="courseSelected" />
            </div>

            <div style="width:100px; float:left;">AUTOCAD</div>
            <select name="fromto[]" class="select small" disabled="disabled" title="Batch">
                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                <option value="May 2012,June 2012">Autocad 1(11:30 AM)</option>
                <option>Batch Name</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

By selecting the check box i need to find the select element, i have tried with closest and parent().next() as well but it doesnt seems to work in this situation.

Comment: where is the checkbox in your markup

Comment: ops sorry my bad..its updated now..

Comment: Why is there an extra `</div>` at the bottom? Why is `select` indented like that, it's not a child of `AUTOCAD div`?

Comment: sorry its edited now..forgot to copy the whole markup..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
if($(this).attr('checked'))  {
    var selects = $(this).parent().parent().find(".select").attr('title');
    alert(selects);
}
...
```

---

```
$(this)          /* checkbox */
.parent()        /* div parent */
.parent()        /* div granfather */
.find(".select") /* look for .select */
.attr('title');  /* get title */
```

anyway, for the sake of simplicity, if you're in control of the markup I would change your markup like so

```
<input name="course[]" type="checkbox" ... data-related-select="yourselect" />
...
<select id="yourselect">
...
```

so the js code would be only

```
var selects = document.getElementById($(this).data('related-select'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(".courseSelected").click(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            var selects = $(this)
                                 .parent() // go to checkbox parent
                                 .next() // jump to div have AUTOCAD
                                 .next(".select") // to select box
                                 .attr('title'); // retrieve the title
            alert(selects);
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the closest first class of object - Jquery

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('.show-all-result').first().show();
```